# How to import or use installed modules from 'node_modules' in my javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

I have been studying from 'Eloquent JavaScript- Third Edition" and in chapter 10 "Modules", we need to install NPM modules 'ordinal' and 'date-names', and book uses it like this:

```
const ordinal = require("ordinal");
const {days, months} = require("date-names");
exports.formatDate = function(date, format) {
return format.replace(/YYYY|M(MMM)?|Do?|dddd/g, tag => {
if (tag == "YYYY") return date.getFullYear();
if (tag == "M") return date.getMonth();
if (tag == "MMMM") return months[date.getMonth()];
if (tag == "D") return date.getDate();
if (tag == "Do") return ordinal(date.getDate());
if (tag == "dddd") return days[date.getDay()];
});
};
const {formatDate} = require("./format-date");
console.log(formatDate(new Date(2019, 8, 13),
"dddd the Do"));
// ! Friday the 13th
```

But when I type this in a JavaScript file in Visual Studio Code, it doesn't recognize what is 'ordinal' or 'date-names'. I installed these packages using 'npm install `package_name`' command. But how do I use them.
And is "package.json" same as "launch.json" of Visual-Studio-Code, because up until now, I have not made or used any file called "package.json". Please if you could, provide a link to study basics of using modules in JavaScript files.

Answer (score 0):

For starting the node application and before installing node modules you need to initialize it using this command

```
npm init
```

And no launch.json is not equivalent to package.json

The launch.json file is used to configure the debugger in Visual Studio Code

package.json is a plain JSON(Java Script Object Notation) text file which contains all metadata information about Node JS Project or application.

Comment: I got it working, thank you sir. Just one more request, will doing this "npm init" will also solve Visual Studio Code error that says, `make type:"module" or use ".cjs" extension on the file`.